# How to define DynamoDB table with global secondary index in serverless framework

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

### My DynamoDB table

- awsRequestID (S)
- ttl (N)
- createdate (S) (ISO)
- user_id (S)
- message (S)

### What I try to achieve

I want to have a global secondary index so I can query to filter all the messages of a users and I get them ordered (using the sort key) as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

### serverless.yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    EventsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.eventsTable}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: awsRequestID
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: ttl
            AttributeType: N
          - AttributeName: createdate
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: user_id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: message
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: awsRequestID
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: UserIdIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: user_id
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdate
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: ttl
          Enabled: true
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

### Error when I deploy

> An error occurred: EventsTable - Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes.

Comment: If I add manually the secondary index in the console with the sort key, it works. So I guess I wrote something wrong

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently the right syntax is this.

These were the errors:

- You cannot add the ttl column to AttributeDefinitions (otherwise you get the error of the question)
- You must have the columns you need for the global secondary index in the attribute definitions (otherwise you get the exact same error)
- You must not have extra columns (message) in the attribute definitions (all give the exact same error message)

```
resources:
  Resources:
    EventsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.eventsTable}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: awsRequestID
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: user_id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdate
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: awsRequestID
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: UserIdIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: user_id
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdate
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: ttl
          Enabled: true
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```